# Raspberry Pi OS dmesg reports ext3,ext2,ext4 Unknown parameter 'uid'

Tags: raspbian

After upgrading the OS to version 6.1.19 on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3 the **Unknown parameter 'uid'** appeared in the dmesg log. It does not to appear to be a problem but I want to know how or what makes this happen.

Linux p1monitor 6.1.19-v7+ #1637 SMP Tue Mar 14 11:04:52 GMT 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux

```
[   18.402229] ext3: Unknown parameter 'uid'
[   18.402292] ext2: Unknown parameter 'uid'
[   18.402338] ext4: Unknown parameter 'uid'
[   18.475880] ext3: Unknown parameter 'uid'
[   18.475927] ext2: Unknown parameter 'uid'
[   18.475958] ext4: Unknown parameter 'uid'
[   18.547705] ext3: Unknown parameter 'uid'
[   18.547752] ext2: Unknown parameter 'uid'
[   18.547783] ext4: Unknown parameter 'uid'
```

```
proc            /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=8fba3cdc-01  /boot           vfat    defaults,ro       0       2
PARTUUID=8fba3cdc-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
tmpfs /p1mon/mnt/ramdisk tmpfs defaults,noatime,nosuid,mode=0777,size=100m 0 0
# a swapfile is not a swap partition, no line here
#   use  dphys-swapfile swap[on|off]  for that
```

output of df

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       60965716 1785628  56050796   4% /
devtmpfs          438956       0    438956   0% /dev
tmpfs             472236      24    472212   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs             188896   22820    166076  13% /run
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs             102400   46624     55776  46% /p1mon/mnt/ramdisk
/dev/mmcblk0p1    261868   52076    209792  20% /boot
log2ram           102400   29828     72572  30% /var/log
tmpfs              94444       0     94444   0% /run/user/1000
```

Comment: what does your `/etc/fstab` look like

Comment: Please edit your question and post /etc/fstab

Comment: the lines prior to these dmesg entries might possibly tell us during what these things happend – but @JaromandaX is on point: this is probably due to an invalid mount option in your fstab.

Comment: added /etc/fstab content. This is not changed after the upgrade to 6.1.9. I also use log2ram as ram filesystem.

Comment: added df outtput.

Comment: upgrade to version Linux-6.1.21-v7+-armv7l-with-glibc2.31dit not fixed this.  Is there a way to find out witch process is sending the messages?